REST API: Find Point Features in one layer that intersect with Polygon Features in another layer
I have a point layer and I have a polygon layer. I am looking for a way, using REST API for an ArcGIS Map Service, to pull all point features that fall within (intersect) any polygon features in the other layer. I attempted this by querying the polygon features, then for each feature, pass its geometry to the query for the point layer. Problem I'm running into is that the polygon layer has a single feature and the JSON to represent the polygon is too large to send through a URL.
Is there a way to do an intersect query on the point layer and pass in the polygon layer?

What type of REST API are you referring to? Google Earth Engine? Some other? phrased like this, this question can mean literally any API that is RESTful.

Sorry. I should have been more clear. I'm using a the Rest API to a ArcGIS Map Service.

If the feature is too large to be represented in JSON, it's probably won't be any better in any other query. You need to crack the "Godzilla" polygon before doing the query.

No worries, I was routine-commenting on unclear questions :) welcome to the site!
